# CakeDC search plugin not working, no errors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakedc

I am working on view which displays all reservations(I am making reservations app) and has form to search. I am using CakeDC Plugin, but it doesn't work.

Here is my action:

```
public function index() {

    if (!App::import('Component', 'Search.Prg')) {
        throw new MissingPluginException(array('plugin' => 'Search'));
    }
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    //$this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->Reservation->parseCriteria(/*$this->Prg->parsedParams()*/);
    //$this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    $searchTerm = '';
    //$this->Prg->commonProcess($this->modelClass, $this->modelClass, 'search', false);

    $by = null;
    if (!empty($this->request->params['named']['searchTerm'])) {
        $searchTerm = $this->request->params['named']['searchTerm'];
        $by = 'any';
    }
    $this->request->data[$this->modelClass]['searchTerm'] = $searchTerm;      



    $this->set('reservation_mode', Configure::read('webakis.reservation_type'));
    $this->Reservation->recursive = 0;

    $this->paginate = array(            
        'fields' => array('Reservation.id', 'Reservation.start', 'Reservation.ucode', 'Reservation.ticket_nr', 'Location.name', 'User.username', 'User.id', 'Opmenu.name', 'Queue.name'),
        'conditions' => array(
            //   'ucode <>' => 0,
            'user_id <>' => 0,
            'deleted' => 0,
        //  'start >=NOW() '
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Reservation.start' => 'asc'
        ),
        //'search',
        'limit' => 12,
        'by' => $by,
        'search' => $searchTerm,
    );        

    $this->set('reservations', $this->paginate($this->modelClass));
    $this->set('searchTerm', $searchTerm);
    $this->set('model', $this->modelClass);
}
```

My form in view:

```
<?php    
echo $this->Form->create($model, array(
'action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('searchTerm', array(
'label' => false, 'style' => 'float:left;', 'class' => 'offset1'));
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search'), array('class' => 'btn', 'style' => ''));

echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

My code in Model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

public $filterArgs = array(
    array('name' => 'searchTerm', 'type' => 'like', 'fields'=>array(/*'Reservation.start', 'Reservation.ucode', 'Reservation.ticket_nr', 'Location.name',*/ 'User.username'/*, 'Opmenu.name', 'Queue.name'*/)));
```

UPDATE:

I included this to make it work, but it's probably not best way:

```
    $conditions = array();
    $conditions[] = array("Reservation.start LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("Reservation.ucode LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("Reservation.ticket_nr LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("Location.name LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("User.username LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("Opmenu.name LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $conditions[] = array("Queue.name LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
```

Comment: That looks highly unconventional.. Why not using the documented (and working) approach? `$this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->User->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams());`

Comment: Because I get `Error: Call to undefined method PrgComponent::parsedParams()`

Comment: Maybe you are using an outdated version?

Comment: I am using Version 2.1 for cake 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after reading readme of my Plugin, I got it working.

Here is my Model code:

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
public $filterArgs = array(
    'searchTerm' => array(
        'type' => 'like', 
        'field'=>array('Reservation.start', 'Reservation.ucode', 'Reservation.ticket_nr', 'Location.name', 'User.username', 'Opmenu.name', 'Queue.name')),
    'filter' => array('type' => 'query', 'method' => 'orConditions'));

public function orConditions($data = array()) {
    $filter = $data['filter'];
    $cond = array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Reservation.start LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'Reservation.ucode LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'Reservation.ticket_nr LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'Location.name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'User.username LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'Opmenu.name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            'Queue.name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ));
    return $cond;
}
```

Controller:

```
public $components = array('Search.Prg');
public $presetVars = true;

public function index() {

    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = array();
    $conditions = $this->Reservation->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    $searchTerm = ''; 

    $this->set('reservation_mode', Configure::read('webakis.reservation_type'));
    $this->Reservation->recursive = 0;

    $this->paginate = array(            
        'fields' => array('Reservation.id', 'Reservation.start', 'Reservation.ucode', 'Reservation.ticket_nr', 'Location.name', 'User.username', 'User.id', 'Opmenu.name', 'Queue.name'),
        'conditions' => array(
            //   'ucode <>' => 0,
            'user_id <>' => 0,
            'deleted' => 0,                
        //  'start >=NOW() '
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Reservation.start' => 'asc'
        ),         
        'limit' => 12,

    );        

    $this->set('reservations', $this->paginate($this->modelClass, $conditions));
    $this->set('searchTerm', $searchTerm);
    $this->set('model', $this->modelClass);
}
```